# BitBucket with Microsoft Team Services for Continuous Integration

Tags: continuous-integration, bitbucket, azure-devops

Is it possible to use BitBucket with Microsoft Team Services for Continuous Integration?  We want to automate the deployment processes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you must use a third party like Zapier (https://zapier.com/zapbook/bitbucket/visual-studio-online/).
This feature is submitted in Uservoice to be included natively : https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/10674648-enable-ci-build-support-for-bitbucket-git-reposito

Comment: Looked at the Zapier option. Is there a way to get it to only trigger for commits to certain branch? The only trigger I see is changeset based, which could be any of them. My structure is across multiple branches, each targeting a different server environment.

Answer (score 0):

This [TechNet article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34313.visual-studio-team-services-connecting-a-bitbucket-repository.aspx), dated May 2016, seems to suggest you can actually setup a connection to your BitBucket repository.

It basically says to go through the following steps:

1. In VSTS, create a Visual Studio build definition
2. During creation, select *Remote Git repository*
3. In BitBucket, copy the same URL repo used when cloning from command line
4. In VSTS repository tab, create a new connection and fill Server URL with the one from BB

Is that what you're after when you say "use BitBucket with Microsoft Team Services for Continuous Integration" ?
HTH

**EDIT:** same is suggested in Option 2 at [this MSDN blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dmx/2016/10/13/integrating-vsts-with-bitbucket/) and in another blog [post](http://rasmustc.com/blog/CI-VSTS-Bitbucket-And-Xamarin/)